# App development in Windows mobile, windows phone 7 and windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

Is there any difference in the development of apps in windows phone 7 and windows phone 8 ?

In windows mobile, its like developing a form based application, but in windows phone 7 everything changed other than c# coding.  In wp7 we use xaml based design instead of forms. Only c# is same for both.

Is there any this kind of difference in developing app in windows phone 7 and 8 ?. Both using same style of coding and same tools and technologies ?. Do I need to study any other other things for windows phone 8 app development ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tools:**

Both WP7 and WP8 needs Visual Studio with proper Windows Phone SDK. For WP7 it's VS2010 and WP7 SDK and for WP8 it's VS2012 with WP8 SDK. There is Visual Studio Express free edition for both. For WP8 development you need Windows 8 (Windows 7 is enough for WP7). There is also one further requirement for WP8 emulator - your processor has to support SLAT.

**Technologies:**

Both WP7 and WP8 uses XAML+C# (or XAML+VB.NET) for app development. There are couple differences in details between both, however you shouldn't really bother about that.

Answer (score 4):

According to the coding style both Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8 are same. But you need "Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone" which comes along with the [WP8 SDK](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk). Using WP8 you can develop apps for both WP 7.5 and WP 8.

Windows Phone 8 is an upgrade for Windows Phone 7/7.5. WP8 contains almost everything that WP7 has and adds some additional features to it. Check this link for [What's new in Windows Phone 8](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8)

Answer (score 0):

Both are same. I agree! but the thing is how we can make it better to work with both windows phone 7 and windows phone 8 matters. The Windows Phone 8 SDK already supports developing 
applications for both versions of Windows Phone, and applications targeting Windows Phone 7 will run without modification on Windows Phone 8.

With the conditional coding functionality and its re usability, the windows 8 app development is being working out well. Integration of two separate projects for different platforms of windows phone can be linked using base code. To get the features function on windows phone 8.

Below link is will help you

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/30/developing-for-windows-phones-7-and-8.aspx